# How do you solve: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.panResponder.panHandlers')?

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

Hi my friend how to solve this problem,I have the following sourcode :

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { Container, Header, Content, SwipeRow, View, Text, Icon, Button } from 'native-base';

            class SwipeRowExample extends Component {   
              render() {
                return (
                  <Container>
                    <Header />
                    <Content scrollEnabled={false}>
                      <SwipeRow
                        leftOpenValue={75}
                        rightOpenValue={-75}
                        left={
                          <Button success onPress={() => alert('Add')}>
                            <Icon active name="add" />
                          </Button>
                        }
                        body={
                          <View>
                            <Text>SwipeRow Body Text</Text>
                          </View>
                        }
                        right={
                          <Button danger onPress={() => alert('Trash')}>
                            <Icon active name="trash" />
                          </Button>
                        }
                      />
                    </Content>
                  </Container>
                );
              }
            }

            export default SwipeRowExample;
```

Message obtained: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.panResponder.panHandlers')

But the results displayed :
[image: the results displayed]

Answer (score 0):

`SwipeRow` was removed from the latest version and they recommend [react-native-swipe-list-view](https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view)

to use `SwipeRow` change native base version to `2.12.0`

[SwipeRow (removed)](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#swipeable-single-def-headref)